# How to Count Product group wise with Field name in Monogodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Good day, I have this collections like below,

```
| hubId | ProductStatus | CreatedAt | 
|:---- |:------:| -----:| ---------:|
| xyz  | On the Way    | 2021-01-01
| mlm  | Delivered    |  2021-01-01
| yyy  | Delivered    |  2021-01-01
| xyz  | Delivered    |  2021-01-01
| yyy  | Cancelled    |  2021-01-01
| yyy  | On the Way    | 2021-01-01
| mlm  | On the Way    | 2021-01-01
| mlm  | Delivered    | 2021-01-15
```

hubId is mongodb object Id for hub user.

So I would like to group productStatus by hubId Like below in JSON format

```
{
    "xyz" : {
        "Delivered" : 1,
        "On the Way" : 1
    },
    "mlm" : {
        "On the Way" : 1,
        "Delivered" : 2
    },
    "yyy" : {
        "On the Way" : 1,
        "Delivered" : 1,
        "Cancelled" : 1
    }
}
```

any body help me how to query for such result ?

and populate hub information by hubID.
I did it

```
Product.aggregate({
      $group: {
        _id: "$hub",
        hub: { $addToSet: "$hub" },
        productStatus: { $addToSet: "$productStatus" },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    });
```

But i am new to generate group data in mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the use of [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator within a series of pipelines and a final [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) pipeline to get the desired result.

**Note**: `hubId` is converted to a string during the pipeline operation as [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator works well if the "key" value is a string. So if `hubId` is an ObjectId then [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) is needed when [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) is applied.

You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
Product.aggregate([
    {  "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "hubId": "$hubId",
                "status": "$ProductStatus"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.hubId",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id.status",
                "v": "$count"
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": { "$toString": "$_id" },
                "v": "$counts"
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "counts": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$counts",
                "in": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                        "$$this",
                        { "v":  { "$arrayToObject": "$$this.v" } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        
    } },
    {  "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
    } }  
])
```

which yields the following result document:

```
{
    "xyz" : {
        "Delivered" : 1,
        "On the Way" : 1
    },
    "mlm" : {
        "On the Way" : 1,
        "Delivered" : 2
    },
    "yyy" : {
        "On the Way" : 1,
        "Delivered" : 1,
        "Cancelled" : 1
    }
}
```

This of course does not produce the other status that has zero count but the solution can be a good starting point.

Comment: Give the above edited solution a try and see if it makes sense. Also, is the above result the one which you are expecting i.e. a hash of Ids and the respective status counts? If not, can you also please update your question to include the desired JSON result document, thanks!

Comment: result updated, but after executing your code I am getting MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$toString'

Comment: You may have an incompatible MongoDB version, `$toString` is available in MongoDB 4.0 and newer

Comment: Hello Chridam yes it is working fine now , thank you, I have updated my mongodb and it works,Could you tell me how to populate by this hubid from hubprofile ?

Comment: Because there are essentially multiple questions in your post and I managed to answer the main one, kindly open a new question detailing what you have thus far and your expected JSON result.

Comment: I made it, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817859/how-to-populate-data-using-mongodb-aggregate-framework